# How to use RLMArray to save an Array

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Note: I am fairly new to Realm and Swift, so excuse any obvious things I don't understand.

I have a working UITableView which I plan to populate with tasks. I want the user to be able to add and delete tasks as needed, so I can't hardcode the tasks, and I want the tasks to be saved between app launches. The most obvious way to do this would be to create an array that gets saved in Realm. The problem is, I don't understand how to save an array in Realm. I have read the documentation on the Realm site but have found it rather confusing due to myself still being fairly new to Swift (And that it's in ObjC). How would you create an array and save it? I originally tried this, and when it didn't work I did some research and found that RLMArray isn't actually an array:

```
let ToDoTasksArray: RLMArray = ["Task Goes Here", "Task Goes Here2"]
```

Any help on this? Thanks!

Edit:

I have also tried saving an array into an RLMObject as an object as so:

```
realm.addObject(ToDoTasksArray)
```

But that also doesn't work, which doesn't surprise me. An array is not an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you first need to setup your models so that your todo's can be saved to the realm.

All you need to do is have this in one of your files (Preferably a todo.swift file)

```
class Todo: RLMObject {
  dynamic var name = ""
}
```

Then you can create your first two todos by doing this:

```
var firstTodo = Todo()
firstTodo.name = "My first thing todo!"

var secondTodo = Todo()
secondTodo.name = "My second thing todo!"
```

Then you can save it to the realm

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.addObject(firstTodo)
realm.addObject(secondTodo)
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

Now you can grab all of your todos which returns an array of them

```
let arrayOfTodos = Todo.allObjects()
```

If I were to create a method to save new todos I'd do something like this

```
func createNewTodo(todo: String){
    let todo = Todo()
    todo.name = todo
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    realm.addObject(todo)
    realm.commitWriteTransaction()
}
```

Comment: Then what happens when a user adds a task? For instance, when the user enters the task name and clicks done, using your method, I would then need to create a new variable for the task - so if a user had 20 tasks I would then have 20 variables. Unless I'm understanding this wrong?

Comment: Thats where RLMArray comes into play so that you can store multiple tasks in an array.

Comment: That's correct you would have 20 different instances where each represents a specific task. You can add them as a batch using an NSArray.

RLMArray is mostly used for relationships, so if a task has many subTasks

Comment: @yoshyosh, so all tasks have to be saved as their own instance of the class? It's not possible to save the task as a String, append that into an array, then save the whole array? (Just asking to make sure.)

Comment: Correct, you can pass an array and loop through creating each instance and adding it to the Realm. Your data is still being stored in a table, which then by calling for allObjects from that table you get an array of results. If you had an array of RLMObjects (Todo's) then you could just use realm.addObjects(myArrayOfRLMObjects). Realm would then know how to store each object as an individual item in the table

Comment: Ok, that makes sense - I'll try that when I get back to work on that project. Thanks for the clarification - now I know what's actually going on!

Comment: No problem, I'm thinking about adding a quick start section to the doc's. Would be great to get any feedback form you on how we can improve understanding how to get started with Realm conceptually

Answer (score 9):

Realm saves objects derived from RLMObject, so you need to define class for your task like:

```
@interface Task : RLMObject

@property NSString * task;
@property NSString * description;
@property NSDate * dueDate;
...

@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Task) // define RLMArray<Task>
```

Then create a task list model as:

```
@interface TaskList : RLMObject

@property RLMArray<Task> * tasks;

@end
```

Now you create Task, add it to TaskList and save:

```
RLMRealm * realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];

Task * task = [Task new];
task.task = @"Some new task";

RLMArray <TaskList> * tasksLists = (RLMArray <TaskList> *)[TaskList allObjects];

// You can manage multiple task lists here using unique primary key for each task list. I am assuming that we have only one list.
TaskList * taskList = tasksLists.firstObject;
[taskList.tasks addObject: task];

[realm addOrUpdateObject: taskList];

[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry I overlooked that you mentioned you are using Swift.

Comment: I needed an example in Obj-C :P. Thnx.