# Add object to RLMArray

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to create rlmobject with rlmarray as one of elemnts but cant get it to work.

declaration:

```
 dynamic var contactInfo : RLMArray = RLMArray(objectClassName: "ContactInfoDB")
```

and insertion:

```
tempLocation.contactInfo.addObject(tc)
```

where tc is

```
class ContactInfoDB: RLMObject
```

but somehow after add the array is still empty. Is there eny other way to insert object into rlmarray with swift using realm for objective c, because I need it to work also in iOS7.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been used Realm for Objective-C, but it should be the same. To make any changes on your db, you should follow the steps:

```
realm.beginWriteTransaction()

// Do what you have to do with your Realm objects

realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

This link can help you :  [How to use RLMArray to save an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593683/how-to-use-rlmarray-to-save-an-array)

Comment: this is correct, you need to persist that change that you made to the array

Comment: well in my case its not changing an object that is in db but creating new one, but I'll still try

Comment: at the end I found out that there wasn't any problems in how I was adding items to array, the problem was in creating and then reading items for/from array.

But still thanks for help