# Using RLMArray without initialisation not possible?

Tags: ios, realm

I would like to collect some data in a method. The `RLMArray` will then be used as a one to many relationship e.g. `menu.dishes`

```
+ (RLMArray<Dish> *)parseDishesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)resultDictionary {

NSArray *menuDishes = (NSArray*)resultDictionary[@"menuDishes"];

RLMArray<Dish> *dishes;
for (NSDictionary *menuDishDictionary in menuDishes) {
    Dish *dish = [self getDishGetDishfromDictionary:menuDishDictionary];
    [dishes addObject:dish];
    }
return dishes;
}
```

The problem: **the dishes array is always nil.**

Is this really not possible, like the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593683/how-to-use-rlmarray-to-save-an-array) question implies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RLMArray` is a container type that's mostly just useful for storing to-many relationships on Realm objects, and you don't get any of the collection optimizations until you've assigned it to an object, which is why Realm disallows direct initialization of `RLMArray` (`+new` and `-init` are listed as unavailable in the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMArray.html#task_Unavailable%20Methods)).

So your `parseDishesFromDictionary` method should return an `NSArray<Dish *>` that you can then add to your `RLMArray` property using [`-addObjects`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMArray.html#//api/name/addObjects:).

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful!